# Erro ao usar span no CakePHP

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, bootstrap-3

Conforme imagem em anexo eu não consigo usar o span quando eu passo para o padrão do Cake. Alguém pode me ajudar, pfv.

```
<div class='col-md-12'>
  <div class="input-group" >
    <!-- Span Bootstrap -->
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="email1">E-mail:</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="email1">
    </div>
    <!-- Fim Span com Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Span Bootstrap no padrão CakePHP -->
    <div class="input-group" >
      <?php  echo $this->Form->input('email', ['type' => 'text', 'class' => 'input-group-addon', 
              'aria-describedby' => 'email', 'span' => ['class' => 'input-group-addon', 'id'=> 'email', 'text' => 'E-mail']
              ]); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Span Bootstrap no padrão CakePHP -->
</div>
```

Print em anexo abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como fica o HTML gerado pelo cake?

Comment: O resultado em HTML?

Comment: Agora está ficando assim.
https://gist.github.com/FabricioDev/6e18cb38daf4df202f75de778c7c2762

Comment: <div class="input-group" >
                        
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="email">E-mail:</span>
                        <div class="input text required"><label for="email"></label><input type="text" name="email" class="input-group-addon" aria-describedby="email" required="required" maxlength="50" id="email" value="email@gmail.com"/></div>

Comment: Acho que tu vai precisar alterar o template, que já deve estar adicionando a div. Dá uma olhada: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses

Comment: Não sei como fazer isso mas descobri que é por causa do asterístico de requerido. Vou tentar alinhar a direita.